# Infinite loop after login with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I've followed tutorial on facebook developers for connect my android app with facebook user's account.
This is my code, so close to tutorial code:

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private LoginButton login_button;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login_fragment,
            container, false);

    login_button = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_facebook);
    login_button.setFragment(this);
    // permissions
    // login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // TODO success

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && !session.isClosed()) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, "publish_actions");
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("FACEBOOK", "Logged in...");

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("FACEBOOK", "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

but after login, my code goes on infinite loop inside onSessionStateChange function (on logout this problem doesn't appear). What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the part under "// TODO success" in onActivityResult, do everything in onSessionStateChange

Comment: i obtain an exception:


    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

Comment: try adding this in the buttons onclicklistener (act is the activity):                 Session.openActiveSession(act, true, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"), new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {...}}

Answer (score 0):

You can't request for any permission in login process.
once login process completed then only request for permissions in another event(like pressing another button something).